# Rails validates_uniqueness_of, logical AND

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have three paramaters, e.g. `site_id_1` and `site_id_2.` and `transport_distance`

When creating a new record, rails should validate that `site_id_1` AND `site_id_2.` dont already exist. (So the combination matters)

With `validates_uniqueness_of(:site_id_1, :site_id_2)` it says that site_id_1 or site_id_2 already exist. 
I've also tried: `validates_uniqueness_of(:site_id_1 && :site_id_2)` but it doesnt helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `scope` param of [`validates_uniqueness_of`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of) validator:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :site_id_1, scope: :site_id_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 style:

```
validates :site_id_1, uniqueness: {scope: :site_id_2}
```